# Python Pandas Groupby-apply duplicate execution

Tags: python, pandas

Why are there 3 executions of the following code?  I only expected it to execute twice, once for each group (foo and bar), and there are two executions over bar.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'type' : ['foo', 'bar'], 'cost' : [1, 4]})


def testFunction(currDf):
    print currDf
    return currDf

grouped_df = df.groupby(['type']).apply(testFunction)

grouped_df

cost type
1     4  bar
cost type
1     4  bar
cost type
0     1  foo
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html#flexible-apply)

pandas is figuring out if you are mutating the input data. it will decide whether a fast or slower path can then be used in the computation.

Comment: Thanks, there was no mention of that here: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html

Comment: its not specific to apply, but more general in groupby, nor is ever point mentioned in the doc-string.